# What is an equivalent of git rm -r ... in the emacs magit package?

Tags: emacs, git

I want remove some folders from my repository and I can do it as usual with

```
git rm -r junk-folder
```

But how I can do this from emacs with *magit* package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Magit doesn't support `git rm`. Instead, delete the folder in `dired`, and then stage the change.